# How do I find an Azure policy definition by name using the Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

Azure's Policy service comes with many built-in policies.  They can be accessed using Azure's Java SDK and the Azure Resource Manager.  The definition of a specific policy can be acquired using the `getByName()` [method in the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.resources.fluentcore.arm.collection.supportsgettingbyname.getbyname?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_resourcemanager_resources_fluentcore_arm_collection_SupportsGettingByName_getByName_java_lang_String_).

The code looks like this:

```
AzureResourceManager azureResourceManager = AzureResourceManager
        .authenticate(credential, profile)
        .withSubscription("<my-subscription-id>");       
PolicyDefinition policyDefinition = azureResourceManager.policyDefinitions().getByName("<name>");
```

To test this code, I went to the console to find the name of a pre-built policy.  I found two different names, one in the text:

[image]

and a different one in the definition:

[image]

However, trying to retrieve the policy definition using either of these names results in the same error:

```
Status code 404, The policy definition 'Audit VMs that do not use managed disks' could not be found.
```

and

```
Status code 404, The policy definition '06a78e20-9358-41c9-923c-fb736d382a4d' could not be found
```

Question:  What name is this method looking for?  Or is there a better way to retrieve a policy definition?

Comment: The name is "06a78e20-9358-41c9-923c-fb736d382a4d" which you should use in your code. another name is display name. But I'm not familiar with java, you should open fiddler to check the detailed error, or you can choose to use the related api [Policy Definitions - Get Built In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/policydefinitions/getbuiltin).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but as I explain in my question, that name results in the error above.  And the link you give is for the REST API, not the Java API.

Comment: yes, it's not java api. I mean you can try it by using the REST API, and open fiddler to check the request details. Then also use fiddler to check the request details when using your java code. At last, you can compare the 2 requests to see if there're any differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get one build_in policy in java application, you can use the method `PolicyClientImpl.getPolicyDefinitions().getBuiltIn()` in the package `com.azure.resourcemanager.resources`. Besides, please note that the name of build-in policy is guide.

For example

1. install sdk

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-resources</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Code

```
String clientId="";
        String clientSecret="";
        String tenant="";
        String subId="";
        AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(tenant,subId, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
                .tenantId(tenant)
                .build();
        PolicyClientImpl policyClient= new PolicyClientBuilder()
                .pipeline(HttpPipelineProvider.buildHttpPipeline(credential,profile))
                .endpoint(profile.getEnvironment().getResourceManagerEndpoint())
                .subscriptionId(profile.getSubscriptionId())
                .buildClient();

        PolicyDefinitionInner policy = policyClient.getPolicyDefinitions().getBuiltIn("04d53d87-841c-4f23-8a5b-21564380b55e");
        System.out.println(policy.policyType());
        System.out.println(policy.description());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wound up using the REST API to get the policy definition when I all know is the policy definition name.  Note that I had to use a one call to get built-in policies and another to get custom policies, which is painful since I didn't know a priori which type I had.  I used [OkHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/) to handle the heavy lifting.  Here's my solution:

```
Boolean itMightBeACustomPolicy = false;
OkHttpClient builtinPolicyDefinitionHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

String builtinPolicyDefinitionUrl = "https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/" 
        + policyState.getString("policyDefinitionName") // This is what I know
        + "?api-version=2020-09-01";

Request builtinPolicyDefinitionRequest = new Request.Builder()
    .url(builtinPolicyDefinitionUrl)
    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    .get()
    .build();

String policyDefinitionJson = "";
try
{
    Response builtinPolicyDefinitionResponse = builtinPolicyDefinitionHttpClient.newCall(builtinPolicyDefinitionRequest).execute();
    if(builtinPolicyDefinitionResponse.isSuccessful())
    {
        // It's a built-in policy definition
        policyDefinitionJson = builtinPolicyDefinitionResponse.body().string();
    }
    else
    {
        // Let's try for a custom definition
        // I do this separately to keep the try..catch unique.
        itMightBeACustomPolicy = true;
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace(); // TODO Handle this...
}  

if(itMightBeACustomPolicy)
{
    OkHttpClient customPolicyDefinitionHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    String customPolicyDefinitionUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" 
            + subscriptionId 
            + "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/" 
            + policyState.getString("policyDefinitionName") // This is what I know
            + "?api-version=2020-09-01";

    Request customPolicyDefinitionRequest = new Request.Builder()
        .url(customPolicyDefinitionUrl)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        .get()
        .build();
    try
    {
        Response customPolicyDefinitionResponse = customPolicyDefinitionHttpClient.newCall(customPolicyDefinitionRequest).execute();
        if(customPolicyDefinitionResponse.isSuccessful())
        {
            policyDefinitionJson = customPolicyDefinitionResponse.body().string();
        }
        else
        {
            // Not sure what it is.  Let's assume there are no policy definitions available.
            // So do nothing here for now.
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); // TODO Handle this...
    }  
}
// Wherever we got the policy definition from, let's parse it and gather data.
// NOTE:  This design assumes that the JSON for built-in and custom are (nearly) identical.
//        That might be wrong.
if(!policyDefinitionJson.isEmpty())
{
    JSONObject policyDefinitionRootObject = new JSONObject(policyDefinitionJson);
    // Do something with the resulting JSON
    System.out.println(policyDefinitionRootObject.getJSONObject("properties").getString("policyType"));
    System.out.println(policyDefinitionRootObject.getJSONObject("properties").getString("description"));
    System.out.println(policyDefinitionRootObject.getJSONObject("properties").getString("displayName"));
}
```

Note:  "OkHttp performs best when you create a single OkHttpClient instance and reuse it for all of your HTTP calls."  So I need to do some re-factoring still to avoid creating multiple clients.